# Drawing a different image for two objects of the same class

Tags: c++, qt

I have two objects, whitepawn and blackpawn, that are of type Piece. Everything about these two objects is the same except for the image used. Currently this is the code I use to draw the white pawn,

```
void Pawn::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    pixmap.load(":/whitepawn.png");

    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.drawPixmap(x, y, pixmap);
}
```

Is there a way to use a different image for blackpawn with making a new class and overriding the new class's paintEvent function?

Edit: The old title was for a different question, ignore that if you saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual functions are the standard solution here:

```
class Pawn
{
  virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) { }
  // ...
};

class WhitePawn : public Pawn
{
  virtual voidpaintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
  {
    pixmap.load(":/whitepawn.png");
    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.drawPixmap(x, y, pixmap);
  }
};

// similar for class BlackPawn
```

Now you can call `Pawn * p = new BlackPawn; p->paintEvent(e);` and get the correct function. (The term here is "overriding", not "overloading", which is something different.)

---

Edit: Seeing Owen's fine answer, another idea that requires changing the constructors is to make the filename a member variable:

```
class Pawn
{
  public: Pawn(const std::string & filename = "") : m_filename(filename) { }
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
  {
    if (m_filename == "") return;

    pixmap.load(m_filename);
    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.drawPixmap(x, y, pixmap);
  }
  // ...
  private: std::string m_filename;
};

class BlackPawn : public Pawn
{
  public: BlackPawn() : Pawn(":/blackpawn.png") { }
};
```

Comment: Yea, my backup plan was your first method, but I didn't want to make a separate class for each pawn since they're so similar. And your second solution is really nice too, but again, I'm avoiding extra classes.Edit: So turns out Owen made a mistake, so I'm going with your second method.

Comment: @gsingh: Well, there aren't any extra classes here, since you said you already have the two derived classes, but changing the base class is certainly more intrusive than Owen's idea with a virtual function returning the string value.

Comment: Ah, I too misunderstood and thought you already had derived classes! OK, if you *don't* want derived classes, you can just keep the base class from my second example and put the file name in the constructor.

Comment: @Kerrer: Actually, that was a typo on my part, see the comment on Owen's post. Sorry.

Comment: @gsingh: I see. Please don't say "inherit" in your post then! :-)

Comment: @Kerrer: Ahh, I didn't fix that either... Sigh, I wrote this post in such a rush. Sorry about all this. Thanks for the answers though, they helped.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can

```
class Pawn {
    public:
    virtual char const* imageFileName() = 0;
};
```

Sorry, I was skimpy on the explanation last time and made it look like there weren't extra classes, there really should be:

```
class WhitePawn : public Pawn {
    public:
    virtual char const* imageFileName();
};
```

Then override (+ declaration):

```
char const* WhitePawn::imageFileName() { return "./whitepawn.png"; }

char const* BlackPawn::imageFilename() { return "./blackpawn.png"; }
```

and call `imageFilename()` from `paintEvent()`:

```
void Pawn::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    pixmap.load(imageFilename());

    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.drawPixmap(x, y, pixmap);
}
```

---

But I personally like Kerrek's idea of making it a variable. You could even do that without making extra classes:

```
class Pawn {
    public:
    Pawn(char const *filename) : filename(filename) { }

    private:
    char const *filname;
};

Pawn whitePawn("./whitepawn.png");
```

Comment: Very nice, much better than my override of the whole function! Actually, you could even make the filename a member variable...

Comment: Oh, I thought only classes could override the inherited classes functions. I didn't know you could override functions for specific objects! Thanks, that helps alot.

Comment: @gsingh2011 Oh no, I misinterpreted! I thought BlackPawn and WhitePawn were classes. No, unfortunately it won't work for just objects.

Comment: But as Kerrek says, you could make it a variable.

Comment: @Owen Oh, ok. I got excited :( Anyway, Kerrek's method is good too. And the misinterpretation was my fault, I meant that both "objects" inherited from the class "Piece", not "Pawn".

Comment: Couldn't you also just overload the method? paintEvent(QPaintEvent *, String) and have it use the other as a helper?

Comment: @Tony Ah, normally, yes, but in Qt `paintEvent` is a callback used by all `QWidget`s to draw to the screen.

Comment: @Owen Then write custom signals/slots? Haha. However, good call.